# What is the best practice for creating a User entity and an Admin entity in a Springboot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

What is the best practice for creating user entities in a Spring Boot application - creating separate entities for users and administrators, or creating a single user entity with a role attribute?

Comment: Single user entity with attribute is in most ways the best thing to go for, because it's easier to implement and easier to extend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, going with a single user entity is the best practice, and you could add the role attribute to it to handle any functionality access through that role.